# Defining logo insertion to the left and right side in the class file

Tags: documentclass-writing, logos

I am trying to create a LaTeX class fille that automatically inserts two logos on the title page, one to the left and one on the right.

This is how I am defining it.

```
  \def\@maketitle{%
  \setlength\parindent{\z@}
  \ifnum\cup@author@cnt<\z@\relax
    \cup@warning{No authors defined: At least one author is required}%
  \fi
  
  \newpage\vspace*{\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight\relax}
     
  \parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-26mm\relax}{%
     \includegraphics[width=16mm, left]{jpc-logo.pdf} 
    \hfill 
    \includegraphics[width=21mm, right]{favicon-logo-black.pdf}
    \centering
     \par \firstheadsize{\journalnamefont\cup@journal@name} 
    (\cup@year), {\volumefont\cup@vol}, \thepage--\pageref{LastPage}
    \par doi:{\cup@doi}
    }
```

This is working fine, except that the second logo is shifted slightly towards the left. How can I make the two images align to left and right with the text at the center.

I have tried some of the suggestions provided here. However, they involve declaring the logos in the tex file. I want this to be dynamic (considering different journals).

Comment: Try `\centering` before the parbox, Remove left and right inside \includegraphics.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Added  ```\centering``` before parbox, removed left and right inside. But it did not work. Them I changed ```\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-26mm\relax}``` to ```\parbox[b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-4mm\relax}```, which gave me good results as expected.